# PHP:Prepared statement?

Tags: php

```
 $stmt=  mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT news_ttitle,pic_name,news_text,id FROM news order by rand()");
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi');
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $tittle,$pic_name,$text,$id);
       mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

All tutorials with " Where " clause, my script without Where and Error.

I know that with "Where" cluse in `(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi');)` must add variable `(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi',$variable,...);)`.
    I don't without "Where" clause where is problem?

```
"Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given"
```

Comment: I didn't understand the use you made of parameter binding here.

Comment: Using prepared statements is for using variables in your query (to prevent SQL-injection). This has nothing to do with the WHERE-clause, as that's often a variable. Also, if your prepare fails, it'll return a boolean, instead of a handle.

Comment: Like @Qirel said, there is no need to use bindings if you aren't binding anything to your query string. Nevertheless, your query is probably wrong, since it seems to return false. Test it in isolation.

Comment: your query is failing, most likely due to a syntax or typo error, ie. `news_ttitle` might need to be `news_title`, or you are referencing a column that does not exist.

Comment: Sean->Yes syntax error in news_ttitle, but next error is mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: Use `echo $conn->error;` to see the error messages from MySQL. It most likely fails in the SQL part, since you do not receive a valid statement handle. (Boolean false is also an indicator for a failed query.)

Comment: my problem is solved, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any conditions or variable names so there's no reason to bind ap arameter, remove these lines.

```
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi');
```

and Remove the variables from this.

```
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $tittle,$pic_name,$text,$id);
```

This isn't tested so you'll have to play around with it some.

Comment: Well, it isn't quite the **root** of the problem, his statement is returning false.

Comment: <h4 class=" text-center"><?php echo $tittle ?></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo 'upload/' . $pic_name; ?>"  alt=""/></p>
                </div>         
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 well serviceColor">
                    <div class="textnews"><?php echo substr($text, 0, 320) . '...'; ?><strong><a href="readnews.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>

Comment: @BryantFrankford You can't remove the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`! That's  how he gets the values from the database stored into a variable he can use in PHP... He can only remove `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. But the issue at hand seems to be that the query is failing.

Comment: This is fix my problem, all script Work !